# What is this JavaScript line doing (Google Maps API)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
var bounds = {
17: [[20969, 20970], [50657, 50658]],
18: [[41939, 41940], [101315, 101317]],
19: [[83878, 83881], [202631, 202634]],
20: [[167757, 167763], [405263, 405269]]
};
```

(found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay)

I found this off the Google Maps Javascript API and I'm trying to figure out how exactly it works in relation to the map and overlay itself. To me, this looks like bounds is an object that declares 17, 18, 19, and 20 as arrays consisting of two sub arrays.

EDIT: What I really want to know is how bounds interacts with the rest of the code I link. Are these coordinates on where to place the overlay?

Comment: `is this wrong` - do you mean your interpretation, or it's validity? ... bounds will be an object with keys of 17,18,19,20, each with an array of 2  arrays of 2 numbers

Comment: I meant my interpretation. I should've specified. Thanks!

Comment: I think your interpretation is accurate enough (mine isn't any better :p )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (zoom < 17 || zoom > 20 ||
      bounds[zoom][0][0] > coord.x || coord.x > bounds[zoom][0][1] ||
      bounds[zoom][1][0] > coord.y || coord.y > bounds[zoom][1][1]) {
    return null;
}
return ['http://www.gstatic.com/io2010maps/tiles/5/L2_',
      zoom, '_', coord.x, '_', coord.y, '.png'].join('');
```

`bounds` displays the image according to the zoom (17, 18, 19, 20 is a zoom level) and depending on your position on the map (x & y). The arrays contain the coordinate x and y (minimum and maximum) depending on the zoom.

If you are out of the coordinates (when you scroll on the map) or if you have a zoom level too big, the picture is not displayed.

Comment: How would I go about finding the (x,y) coordinates on a particular map?

Comment: I don't know, but you can test the value in live with `console.log(coord.x + ' ' + coord.y )` and use the desired value.